# Change android accessibility tools properties?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-a11y

[image]I am conducting accessibility testing on my android application, and am running into a few accessibility issues.

I want to know if it possible to change any properties of the accessibility tools in code, such as change the color or size of the focus selector?

Right now the focus selector is hard to see in some parts of the application. I have not found anything that states you can change this. Thank you for your help

Edit(Picture added):
Attached is an example of my login screen with accessibility mode on. In the picture, the cancel button is focused, but as seen in the picture the focus selector is very hard to see. I want to make the selector more visible if it is possible.

Comment: You need to change the settings inside *your* code, not the accessibility tools. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669298/trying-to-change-tab-indicator-color for some hints

Comment: @RyanB Thank you for the response. The link you provided will help for changing a selected item's view, but does not help in making the accessibility focus more visible. I have added more information and an image to illustrate my issue.

Comment: (a student in programing) is that html UI ? because  andriod Buttons and EditText have no issues with selection as far as i have experienced

Comment: @SrinathGanesh The UI is coded completely in Android and works as expected. However, in accessibility mode, the focus selector is not that visible and shown in the image. I want to made it more visible for accessibility purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessibility service is a global-level service; even if your app can change settings on the service itself, you should avoid doing so because you'll need to reverse those changes when your app is no longer active (and that gets you into some nasty corner cases... What if your app crashes and leaves the user's accessibility service in a bad state?).

Alternatively, you can use the [Accessibility Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html) to check the status of accessibility on the system (via `addAccessibilityStateChangeListener` and `isEnabled`) and when you detect accessibility is enabled, change your app's UI to be more accomodating to the accessibility system (for example, by significantly lightening the app's gradient background so the green highlight box becomes visible). Your users who don't need accessibility get the app's interface as you've intended it, and your users who need assistance with vision can still use accessibility.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know that attempting any change to accessibility is  a bad thing, and that the lack of information to the make the changes confirmed that as well. I will try what you said with the StateChangeListener and hopefully that will make the focus more visible.